# mathop shifts the baseline, DeclareMathOperator doesn't

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Here is a little example that illustrates this strange behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\foo{\mathbf{l}}
\begin{document}
baseline$\mathbf{l}$baseline$\mathop{\mathbf{l}}$baseline$\mathop{l}$baseline$\foo$baseline
\end{document}
```

[image: baselines]

Note that the explict call to `\mathop` shifts the baseline of the `l`. But if you use `\DeclareMathOperator` this doesn't happen. Is this a bug or a feature?

I personally think that the shifted baseline looks really weird if you're discussing an operator in text, so I'd like to shift it up again. Do I have an alternative to endless use of `\DeclareMathOperator`?

Comment: Is `\DeclareMathOperator` not about functions like `sin`, `cos`, etc., and `\mathop` about operators like `+`, `-`, etc.?

Comment: @MartinScharrer if that's the case, the terminology is confusing! there's `\mathbin` and `\mathrel`, I thought they were the ones for the infix notation symbols…

Comment: Ok, yes `\mathbin` is for binary operators! `\mathrel` is for relations, i.e. `=` etc. I don't have *The TeXBook* handy right now, otherwise I would look it up.

Comment: `\mathop` is also about `\sum` and friends, which is why it centers single glyphs vertically on the math axis.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

it's a feature.  here's an excerpt from `amsopn.dtx`:

> In the interior of the `\mathop` we need a null object (we choose a zero kern for
>      minimum waste of main mem) in order to guard against the case where #3 is a single
>      letter; TeX will seize it and center it on the math axis if there is nothing else
>      inside the `\mathop` atom.

and here's the definition of `\qopname` which underlies `\DeclareMathOperator`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qopname}[3]{%
\mathop{#1\kern\z@\operator@font#3}%
\csname n#2limits@\endcsname}
```

Comment: `\operatorname`?

Comment: @egreg -- `\operatorname` is also defined in `amsopn`, but it's defined in terms of `\qopname`.  i'm pretty sure that michael preferred `\DeclareMathOperator` as being more descriptive; he also limited its use to the preamble, and i *know* that he felt strongly that all such commands should be defined only in the preamble.  his documentation (`texdoc amsopn`) is pretty clear, even to a non-guru.

Comment: I was just pointing to `\operatorname` that's the "user level" version of `\qopname (which requires three quite mysterious arguments) and is available also in `document`.

Comment: Why is it considered a feature to have single letter operator names centre on the math axis?

Comment: @Seamus -- it's not single *letter* but single *glyph* operators, in particular `\sum`, `\prod`, `\int`, etc., that are responsible for this.  in the cm extension font, most, if not all, glyphs are positioned entirely below the baseline, and the `\mathop` mechanism used to position them correctly.  i don't know for sure, but it's likely that knuth didn't need single-letter operator names, and didn't think it worth the "cost" of checking for them.  (remember that when tex was written, computers weren't nearly as fast as they are now, and tremendous effort went into making tex efficient.)

Answer (score 23):

The "shifting" obeys TeX rules: when the argument of `\mathop` consists of *one character only* it is centered with respect to the math axis (where the fraction line sits); this is laid down in the TeXbook, Appendix G, Rule 13.

For "one shot" operators you can use `\operatorname`, that cures the problem (and chooses automatically `\mathrm`.

```
$\operatorname{l}$ is different from $\mathop{\mathrm{l}}$
```

The command is available as soon as `amsopn` is loaded (the same package that supplies `\DeclareMathOperator`); it is loaded automatically by `amsmath`.

The *-variant has a similar effect to `\DeclareMathOperator*`, so defines a math operator with limits.

If the input `\operatorname{\mathnormal{l}}` for getting a "normal italic l" is too much, then

```
\mathop{\kern0pt l}
```

is shorter.

Comment: If you use `\newcommand\foo{\kern0pt l}` then `\foo` still has the baseline shifted. I assume this is some expansion magic, but how might one fix that?

Comment: @Seamus Sorry, but I don't get it: `\mathop{\foo}` will not shift `l` from the baseline, while `\foo` simply prints `l`.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\foo{\kern0pt \mathop{l}}
\begin{document}
$l\foo l$
\end{document}`

Note baseline is shifted. That is, the solution you suggest doesn't work when `mathop` is used in defining a new command with only one glyph.

Comment: @Seamus Exactly what's expected: if the list given as argument to `\mathop` consists of a single character, the character is shifted, as I wrote in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I thought adding the `\kern0pt` was supposed to avoid the baseline shift? The point is, when you have the `\kern0pt` inside a `\newcommand` it doesn't do that.

Comment: @Seamus Sorry, but I don't get it: `\kern0pt` must go *inside* the argument to `\mathop`.

Comment: Oh right. and then it works. I was being foolish! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Fixes for `\mathop` are inserting empty space within the argument, such as by `\hspace`, `\kern`, or `\mbox`.

This has the correct baseline:

```
\mathop{\mathbf{l}\mbox{}}
```

Ant this too:

```
\mathop{\mathbf{l}\hspace{0pt}}
```

`amsmath` does it similar, here you can see it in within `\operatorname`, which is called by `\DeclareMathOperator` via `\@declmathop`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qopname}[3]{%
  \mathop{#1\kern\z@\operator@font#3}%
  \csname n#2limits@\endcsname}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about LaTeX, but in plain TeX, the following two solutions are different in respect to superscripts, but the same w.r.t. subscripts: `\mathop{\kern0pt\bf P}\nolimits^H_x` and `\mathop{\hbox{}{\bf P}}\nolimits^H_x`. The latter preserves the location of the superscripts for `\mathord`, as `{\bf P}^H_x`. Here's an illustration of 4 possibilities:

```
${\bf P}^H_x 
\mathop{\kern0pt\bf P}\nolimits^H_x
\mathop{\bf P\kern0pt}\nolimits^H_x
\mathop{\hbox{}{\bf P}}\nolimits^H_x$
```

[image]