# Dot Derivative Discrepancy

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, amsmath

I am trying to typeset some higher-order time derivatives using the dot notation, and I've noticed something strange. The expressions

```
$\dot y + y = \cos(\dot y)$
$\ddot y + y = \cos(\dot y)$
```

give the expected results. However,

```
$\dddot y + y = \cos(\dot y)$
$\ddddot y + y = \cos(\dot y)$
```

causes the higher derivative term to be slightly raised, see below. Any thoughts?

[image]

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, fouriernc}
```

Comment: Your code snippets don't compile for me. Where is `\ds` defined? Please compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I've edited the OP's code for clarity and removed the unnecessary `\ds` terms.

Comment: In addition to the problem of `\dddot`- and `\ddddot`-accented letters not being set correctly on the baseline, it seems there's a second problem: The *size* of the dots for one- and two-dot accents is *smaller* than that of the dots of the three- and four-dot accents. This seems to be a "feature" caused by the loading of the `fouriernc` package: if `amsmath` is loaded without the `fouriernc` package, at least all dots have the same size. (I noticed this problem right away in the image the OP posted, but I don't know if it's so evident to others as well.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem in placement stems from the fact that both `\dddot` and `\ddddot` construct their arguments as `\mathop` in order to place a "limit" on top of it. However, `\mathop` centres its contents vertically on the math axis if the argument is a single character (see [mathop shifts the baseline, DeclareMathOperator doesn't](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41261/5764)) - a feature.

So, you should trick LaTeX in thinking it is actually more than a single character by adding (say) `\hspace{0pt}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, fouriernc}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item $\dot{y} + y = \cos(\dot y)$
  \item $\ddot{y} + y = \cos(\dot y)$
  \item $\dddot{y\hspace{0pt}} + y = \cos(\dot y)$
  \item $\ddddot{y\hspace{0pt}} + y = \cos(\dot y)$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

One can correct automatically the behavior by adding the following code after `\usepackage{amsmath}`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\dddot}[1]{%
  {\mathop{\kern\z@#1}\limits^{\vbox to-1.4\ex@{\kern-\tw@\ex@
   \hbox{\normalfont ...}\vss}}}}
\renewcommand{\ddddot}[1]{%
  {\mathop{\kern\z@#1}\limits^{\vbox to-1.4\ex@{\kern-\tw@\ex@
   \hbox{\normalfont....}\vss}}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: It's clearly a bug in `amsmath`.

Comment: definitely a bug in `amsmath`, reported first in 2003.  curiously, in the original report, submitted with accented uppercase letters, the affected terms were lowered, leading to a slightly different statement of the problem.  but it's the same problem, and it's on our list.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Letters without descenders are lowered, those with discenders and no ascenders are raised. It's curious that `amsmath` has corrected in `\overset` the similar bug in `\stackrel`, but hasn't a `\kern\z@` in `\dddot` and `\ddddot`.

Comment: @egreg -- it's not that a bug was corrected in `\overset`.  the `\kern\z@` in `\overset` was inherited from ams-tex, as were the definitions of `\dddot` and `\ddddot`, and the same bug still exists for those two accents in ams-tex.  it's unlikely that any more bugs will ever be fixed in ams-tex, but thanks for making me check; i'll add them to that list now.  as for `\stackrel`, that's defined in `latex.ltx` so any bug report should go to the latex bugs database -- there's nothing there now, so can you take care of that, please?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I meant that `amsmath` (or `amstex`) took care of not making the same error as in `\stackrel`. I guess it's too late to change `\stackrel` in `latex.ltx`: it's become a feature. :)

Comment: @egreg -- `amstex` existed before latex, and thus before `\stackrel`, and `\overset` occurs relatively frequently compared to multiply-dotted single letters, so it was noticed.  as for a latex misfeature, it's still worth mentioning in the latex bugs database, so it's on the record.

Answer (score 30):

### The short answer

The `accents` package fixes this buggy behaviour of `\dddot` and `\ddddot` (and also a few other issues; see below). If the `accents` versions still don't make you happy, give the code at the end of this answer a try.

### The long answer

Werner gave a great explanation of how the vertical positioning problem arises and how it can be fixed. I'd like to discuss a few more (not quite as conspicious) issues I see with `\dddot` and `\ddddot`. These occur also *without* using the `fouriernc` package (which in addition leads to overly large dots, as Mico noted in his comment to the question), so I didn't load `fouriernc` for producing the screenshots below.

1. [image: comparison dddot versus ddot over y] 
   As one sees in the image, the dots in `\dddot{y\hspace{0pt}}` are quite a bit farther apart than in `\ddot{y}`. (I don't think that this is intentional.)
2. If one looks a bit closer, then one sees that the dots from `\dddot` are also a bit *higher* than those from `\ddot`.
3. With `\dddot` and `\ddddot`, the *horizontal* positioning of the dots isn't satisfactory either, in my opinion. Namely, these commands don't take into account the *skew* of the character like the math accents `\dot` and `\ddot` do. This isn't obvious in the image with `y` above, but a comparison of `\dddot{J\hspace{0pt}}` and `\ddot{J}` makes it clear:
   [image: comparison dddot versus ddot over J]. <sub>(And this is *not* the fault of the `\hspace{0pt}` fix.)</sub>
4. `\dddot` and `\ddddot` don't work properly in sub- and superscripts: the dots have the same size and spacing as in `\textstyle`. But I don't see a real problem here since probably one shouldn't use those commands in sub- and superscripts anyway.
5. On an *overly* pedantic note, the dots in `\dddot` (black) are a few percent larger than those in `\ddot` (red). Moreover, the bounding box of `\dddot{y}` is not quite high enough. The latter *might* be a minor issue, but I didn't encounter any problems.
   [image: pedantic]

---

The `accents` package fixes some of the above issues by redefining `\dddot` and `\ddddot` appropriately. In particular, the dots are placed like accents to that the skew is taken into account, and the dots are closer together. For `\ddddot`, they are in fact noticeably closer together than in `\ddot`. All in all, it looks much better:

[image: example with accents package]

One clearly sees that one would have to put some extra space around `\ddddot{l}` in the right hand side of the above formula. The reason is that the dots are defined in a way that they take up no horizontal space. (This is a side effect of `\ddddot` being defined as a math accent.) On the left hand side this behaviour leads to nice spacing in the left hand side.

Issue #2 is not fixed by `accents`: strangely enough, the package sets the dots a bit *lower* than in `\ddot`. Actually the dots are lowered a bit more than they're raised with `amsmath`. Also point #4 in the list isn't *quite* fixed,  the most obvious point being that `\dddot` doesn't work properly in `\scriptstyle` since the definition contains a `\textstyle` that should be removed:

```
\def\dddot{\accentset{{\cc@style.\mkern-1.7mu\textstyle.\mkern-1.7mu.}}}
```

---

If you're still not quite satisfied with the versions from the `accents` package, then you can use my implementation of `\dddot` and `\ddddot` below which fixes all the issues above (except for the marginally too large dot-size  mentioned in #5 `:-)`). The code only works together with `amsmath` since it hacks into `amsmath`'s accent placement ([just like here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253)). In the image below I compare my implementation (line 1) with the `accents` (line 2) and `amsmath` (line 3) implementations. (Note that I didn't use Werner's fix for `amsmath`.)

[image: comparison of the 3 implementations]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}%, fouriernc}
\let\amsdddot\dddot
\let\amsddddot\ddddot
\usepackage{accents}
\let\accdddot\dddot
\let\accddddot\ddddot
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\dddot[1]{%
  \placeaccent{\acc@dot\mkern1.4mu\acc@dot\mkern1.4mu\acc@dot}{#1}%
  }
\renewcommand*\ddddot[1]{%
  \placeaccent{\acc@dot\mkern1.4mu\acc@dot\mkern1.4mu\acc@dot\mkern1.4mu\acc@dot}{#1}%
  }
\newcommand*\placeaccent[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\acc@dot{\kern-0.08em.\kern-0.08em}%
  \def\acc@skip{\ifx\macc@style\displaystyle0.32
           \else\ifx\macc@style\textstyle0.32
           \else\ifx\macc@style\scriptstyle0.22
           \else0.15\fi\fi\fi ex}%
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
    \setbox6\hbox{$\m@th\macc@style#1$}%
    \@tempdima\wd4
    \advance\@tempdima\macc@kerna
    \advance\@tempdima-\wd6
    \divide\@tempdima\tw@
    \@tempdimb\z@
    \ifdim\@tempdima<\z@ \@tempdimb-\@tempdima \@tempdima\z@ \fi
    \vbox{\offinterlineskip
          \moveright\@tempdima\box6
          \kern\acc@skip
          \moveright\@tempdimb\box4}%
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
  \macc@nested@a\relax111{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\fboxrule0.0001pt
\fboxsep0pt
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\dot y + \ddot y + \dddot y + \ddddot{y} = \cos(\ddddot l)$,
      \quad \fbox{$\dddot{y}$}, \quad
      $\ddot{A}_{\dddot{x}_{\ddddot{x}}} \ne \dddot{A}_{\ddot{x}_{\dot{x}}}$
\let\dddot\accdddot
\let\ddddot\accddddot
\item $\dot y + \ddot y + \dddot y + \ddddot{y} = \cos(\ddddot l)$,
      \quad \fbox{$\dddot{y}$}, \quad
      $\ddot{A}_{\dddot{x}_{\ddddot{x}}} \ne \dddot{A}_{\ddot{x}_{\dot{x}}}$
\let\dddot\amsdddot
\let\ddddot\amsddddot
\item $\dot y + \ddot y + \dddot y + \ddddot{y} = \cos(\ddddot l)$,
      \quad \fbox{$\dddot{y}$}, \quad
      $\ddot{A}_{\dddot{x}_{\ddddot{x}}} \ne \dddot{A}_{\ddot{x}_{\dot{x}}}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If there is need, I can add some explanations to my code.

Answer (score 7):

Unicode has dedicated accent characters for those: `0x20DB` and `0x20DC`.

So with `unicode-math`, `\dddot` and `\ddddot` should work correctly. It should be noted that Will Robertson, the author of `unicode-math`, states in the README:

> I am a little wary of encouraging people to use this package for production work

Nevertheless, Unicode is certainly *The Way Of The Future™*.

Comment: those look like primes, not dots.

Comment: @wh1t3 what they look like here depends on… a gazillion of things. Maybe I'll take them off from the answer since there's no way to make sure the client can see them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest the dot commands if you like, for example `\dot{\ddot{y}}` for the third derivative.

Comment: This would stack rather than spread them.