# mathtools: \dddot cause the term to rise

Tags: mathtools

From [Dot Derivative Discrepancy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42443/dot-derivative-discrepancy), I have tried the using `\hspace{0pt}` and

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\dddot}[1]{%
  {\mathop{\kern\z@#1}\limits^{\vbox to-1.4\ex@{\kern-\tw@\ex@
   \hbox{\normalfont ...}\vss}}}}
\renewcommand{\ddddot}[1]{%
  {\mathop{\kern\z@#1}\limits^{\vbox to-1.4\ex@{\kern-\tw@\ex@
   \hbox{\normalfont....}\vss}}}}
\makeatother
```

after loading `mathtools` but the problem still persists.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\dot{\mathbf{r}}\times\ddot{\mathbf{r}}\times\dddot{\mathbf{r}}
\]
\end{document}
```

In the case the font scheme I am using has any affect as well, the fonts are:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}                 
\linespread{1.05}                  
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}              
\usepackage{eulervm}
\normalfont      
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}           
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

Comment: The construction of `\dot` and `\ddot` is *completely* different from `\dddot` and `\ddddot`. You might be interested in redefining `\dot` and `\ddot` to be similar to `\dddot` and `\ddddot`.

Comment: I've updated my answer introducing some improvements.

Comment: the `\dot` and `\ddot` come directly from a font; the triple and quadruple dots are cobbled together from pieces, so it's not surprising that they behave differently.  the *best* solution, of course, would be for triple and quadruple dots to be in a font, as they should be in a full unicode font.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The definitions of `\dddot` and `\ddddot` need some modifications: the dots need to be lowered a bit and to be scaled down so they are at the same height as in `\ddot` and `\dot`. I also used a `\makebox` of `0pt` width so as to "hide" the extra width added by the dots, the separation between dots was also a little bit reduced.

Using TikZ I drew some horizontal rules to check the alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}                 
\linespread{1.05}                  
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}              
\usepackage{eulervm}
\normalfont      
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}           
\usepackage{textcomp} 

\newcommand\scaleddot{\scalebox{.89}{.}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\dddot}[1]{%
  {\mathop{\kern\z@#1}\limits^{\makebox[0pt][c]{\vbox to-2.2\ex@{\kern-\tw@\ex@
   \hbox{\normalfont\scaleddot\kern-0.5pt\scaleddot\kern-0.5pt\scaleddot}\vss}}}}}
\renewcommand{\ddddot}[1]{%
  {\mathop{\kern\z@#1}\limits^{\makebox[0pt][c]{\vbox to-2.2\ex@{\kern-\tw@\ex@
   \hbox{\normalfont\scaleddot\kern-0.5pt\scaleddot\kern-0.5pt\scaleddot\kern-0.5pt\scaleddot}\vss}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Huge

\[
\dot{\mathbf{r}}\times\ddot{\mathbf{r}}\times\dddot{\mathbf{r}}\times\ddddot{\mathbf{r}}
\]

\[
\dot{r}\times\ddot{r}\times\dddot{r}\times\ddddot{r}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw ([yshift=230.5pt]current page.west) -- +(\paperwidth,0pt);
\draw ([yshift=161.5pt]current page.west) -- +(\paperwidth,0pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since, in this case, `mathtools` is loaded used, one could've used `\mathclap{...}` instead of `\makebox[0pt][c]{...}`; I went with the latter, since in this way the redefinition is also valid without `mathtools`.

Comment: my eyes may be going, but it looks to me like the three-dot embellishment has the dots farther apart than the two-dot version.  in any event, there's more space between the times sign and the third "r" than in any other similar location (which was true also in the original question).

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes; I've reduced a bit the distance between the dots, and fixed the spacing between the times and the third "r". God bless your eyes!

Comment: sorry to be a pain, gonzalo, but it seems that the dots in the triple and quadruple embellishments are just a hair "fatter" than the single and double ones.  getting matching dots isn't easy; i know -- i constructed the first version used at ams, and i think it's still not completely rignt in `amsfonts`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton by no means! Thanks to your comments and keen observations answers are a lot better. I've now scaled down a bit the dots; I can only zoom to 400% and they seem to be OK now. What do you think?

Comment: Your last edit raised the `r` up.

Comment: i think that looks as good as possible.  (i really don't think it would be possible to look good if a four-dotted letter would appear sandwiched in between two other letters, particularly if they were also embellished, but i think the chance of that being needed is pretty slim.)

Comment: @dustin I drew some rules to check the alignment; as far as I can tell the "r" characters appear vertically aligned.

Answer (score 9):

Package `amsmath` uses math accents for `\dot` and `\ddot`, but constructs `\dddot` and `\ddddot` manually as upper limit of a math operator with some disadvantages:

- The argument/symbol is set as math operator, causing a single symbol to be vertically centered around the math axis.
- The dots are set with font `\normalfont`, thus they do not scale in smaller math styles.
- The upper border of the bounding box is different, the accent is included, the manual dots are more or less excluded by the construction.

The `mathabx` fonts have `\dddot` and `\ddddot` as math accents. Because package `mathabx` does change many fonts, the following example defines only the font, needed for the accents and redefines `\dot` up to `\ddddot` to use the `mathabx` fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% from mathabx:
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\let\dot\relax
\DeclareMathAccent{\dot}{0}{mathb}{"39}
\let\ddot\relax
\DeclareMathAccent{\ddot}{0}{mathb}{"3A}
\let\dddot\relax
\DeclareMathAccent{\dddot}{0}{mathb}{"3B}
\let\ddddot\relax
\DeclareMathAccent{\ddddot}{0}{mathb}{"3C}

\begin{document}
\[
  \dot{r}, \ddot{r}, \dddot{r}, \ddddot{r}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The example uses an italics `r` to show that accents (and upper limits) are following the slanting of the symbol.
- The dot accents are a little higher in the `mathabx` font.

Comment: This answer was intended as answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191790/16967). But the question was closed as duplicate and redirected here, before I could answer.

Comment: Don't you agree that the other question was a duplicate of this one?

Comment: @egreg: I would have called it related rather than a duplicate. But never mind, the answer covers an intersection of both questions.

Comment: Thank you @HeikoOberdiek ! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the `stackengine` approach.  I have kerned -1mu between the dots, but that could be changed if you found them wrongly spaced.  I also set the dots 1pt above the object... that too could be customized.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
%\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}                 
%\linespread{1.05}                  
%\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
%\usepackage{courier}              
%\usepackage{eulervm}
%\normalfont      
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}           
%\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\dot[1]{\stackMath\stackengine{1pt}{#1}{.}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\renewcommand\ddot[1]{\stackMath\stackengine{1pt}{#1}{.\mkern-1mu.}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\renewcommand\dddot[1]{\stackMath\stackengine{1pt}{#1}{.\mkern-1mu.\mkern-1mu.}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \dot{\mathbf{r}}\times\ddot{\mathbf{r}}\times\dddot{\mathbf{r}}
\]
\[
  \dot{r}\times\ddot{r}\times\dddot{r}
\]
\[
  \frac{\dot{\mathbf{r}}\times\ddot{\mathbf{r}}\times\dddot{\mathbf{r}}}
       {\lvert \dot{\mathbf{r}} \times \ddot{\mathbf{r}} \rvert}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In response to barbara's comment...

[image]

Comment: to "check" the height, compare the spacing with a macron and a hat.  all of them should look well together.