# Three dots above a symbol look weird

Tags: math-mode, accents

In math mode, when I type

```
\dot{x}, \ddot{x}, \dddot{x}
```

the third expression doesn't look like the two previous ones. The three dots are widely spaced and higher above the symbol. Is there a way to have three dots above a symbol so that it looks more regular compare to one dot and two dots?

[image]