# How can I add more than 4 dots to a derivative?

Tags: math-mode

I have 2 questions :

- What is the maximum limit of dots that I can display above a variable to indicate its derivative ? (I read it somewhere that 4 is the limit. Still not sure)
- How do I print more dots than these in a general form?

Comment: Usually, higher derivatives are written using a number, since it is difficult to read if there are too many dots or primes. For example, the sixth derivative of `y` would be written as `$y^{(6)}$`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you asking about the style of using dots for higher order derivatives? Most times, higher order derivatives (order > 3) are indicated as `f^{(4)}` etc.

Comment: dot typically denotes "time derivative" whereas a prime is a more general derivative notation.  And if the prime is OK, I've seen roman-numerals as superscripts to denote bigger than 3rd order derivatives.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: True, but higher order time derivatives (order > 2) rarely occur (in Physics,unless using the Abraham - Lorentz - Dirac equation of interaction of a charged particle with it's own field). Most likely, the dot indicates derivatives with respect to some parameter.

Comment: @HåkonMarthinsen: I think your reasoning is the best one: It's hard to recognize more then three dots (or primes)

Answer (score 8):

**Edit: Improved version in the second half of this post.**

If you really want to, you could define a new command to include as many dots as you want in the same way as `amsmath` does for three and four dots. Here is an example with any number of dots, using the `multido` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multido}

\makeatletter
\ams@newcommand{\vardot}[2]{%
  {\mathop{#2\kern0pt}\limits^{\vbox to-1.4\ex@{\kern-\tw@\ex@
   \hbox{\normalfont\multido{}{#1}{.}}\vss}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\vardot{6}{x}$
\end{document}
```

The command `\vardot{n}{x}` will print n dots over x.

---

### Improved version

Generalizing the related [answer of Hendrik Vogt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60890/15830), we get much nicer output that fixes many typographical problems of the original `amsmath` commands `\dddot` and `\ddddot`.  This version implements the command `\vardot[n]{x}`, where `n` is the number of dots to put above `x`. The number `n` is an optional argument with default value of 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{accents}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\dddot[1]{%
  \placeaccent{\acc@dot\mkern1.4mu\acc@dot\mkern1.4mu\acc@dot}{#1}%
  }
\renewcommand*\ddddot[1]{%

\placeaccent{\acc@dot\mkern1.4mu\acc@dot\mkern1.4mu\acc@dot\mkern1.4mu\acc@dot}{#1}%
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \vardot {O{1} m }
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF
      {#1} = {1}
      {\dot #2}
      {\placeaccent{\prg_replicate:nn {#1-1} {\acc@dot\mkern1.4mu}\acc@dot}{#2}}
  }
\newcommand*\placeaccent[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\acc@dot{\kern-0.08em.\kern-0.08em}%
  \def\acc@skip{\ifx\macc@style\displaystyle0.32
           \else\ifx\macc@style\textstyle0.32
           \else\ifx\macc@style\scriptstyle0.22
           \else0.15\fi\fi\fi ex}%
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
    \setbox6\hbox{$\m@th\macc@style#1$}%
    \@tempdima\wd4
    \advance\@tempdima\macc@kerna
    \advance\@tempdima-\wd6
    \divide\@tempdima\tw@
    \@tempdimb\z@
    \ifdim\@tempdima<\z@ \@tempdimb-\@tempdima \@tempdima\z@ \fi
    \vbox{\offinterlineskip
          \moveright\@tempdima\box6
          \kern\acc@skip
          \moveright\@tempdimb\box4}%
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
  \macc@nested@a\relax111{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\vardot[6]{x}$
\end{document}
```

I'm sure this code can be improved a lot, since I am not an experienced TeX programmer. I'm not sure if mixing `expl3` code with the LaTeX code of Hendrik Vogt is a good idea, but it seems to work.

Comment: Now define a command `\makehugenumberofdotscommand` that automatically defines `\dddddddddddd` etc.  ;-)

Comment: expl3 will help with @ChristianHupfer's challenge :-) (Well, if you want to autogenerate the command name. It could be done quite simply with plain ole' TeX if you provide the command token yourself.)

Comment: @SeanAllred: Go ahead :D

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I cheated and used `multido`. ;-)

Comment: @HåkonMarthinsen You should use `\mathop{#2\kern0pt}`. The added kern prevents TeX from vertically centering `#2` if it happens to be a single symbol. This is a bug in the `amsmath` code.

Comment: @Dan: I tried your suggestion, but I couldn't see any difference in the output for many different test cases. Can you provide a case where the current version fails?

Comment: @Dan: Nevermind, I see the problem. Fixed it now.