# What's the difference between \DeclareMathOperator and \mathop?

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

Is there any difference between

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{erf}
```

and

```
\def{\erfc}{\mathop{\mathrm{erfc}}}
```

apart of the fact that `\DeclareMathOperator` is defined in `amsmath` package?

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t understand: `\mathop` is a TeX primitive and does *not* define a new command/macro.  In any case, note that `\DeclareMathOperator` defines *robust* commands, and that it has a *-form for managing the behavior of the newly defined operator wrt. “limits”.

Comment: Also, the "Related" is showing [mathop shifts the baseline, DeclareMathOperator doesn't](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41261/107497).

Comment: @Teepeemm: Thank you for providing the reference to a very similar question.  I have got enough reputation to vote to mark the question as a duplicate, as you suggest.