# Vertical dots with same height as colon

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How can I construct three vertical dots similar to `\vdots` but which span the same height as a colon `:`? `\vdots` is usually intended for use in matrices or a set of equations to indicate that there are many elements. I am intending its use within an in-line equation for purposes of operator ordering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a version of `\vdots` that is exactly as tall as a colon you could try to overlay a `\cdot` on top of a `:`. The code below, which is based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/156366) excellent answer, does exactly this.

I'm actually defining several different versions of `\threedots` with different spacing properties:

- `\threedotsord` has the same spacing as ordinary letters;
- `\threedotsopen` and `\threedotsclose` have the same spacing as opening and closing parentheses respectively;
- `\threedotsbin` has the same spacing as a binary operator (like `+`, `-`, `\times`,…);
- `\threedotsrel` has the same spacing as a relation symbol (like `=`, `<`, `\sim`, `\rightorrow`, …).

Which version you need will depend on how you intend to use the symbol. Since you're talking about [operator ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path-ordering), you will probably want to use `\threedotsopen` and `\threedotsclose`. For convenience, I defined a macro `\oporder` that puts a pair of triple dots with the correct spacing around its argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter %% <- make @ usable in macro names
\newcommand*\superimpose[2]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\@firstoftwo#2$\cr
           \hidewidth$\m@th#1\@secondoftwo#2$\hidewidth}%
}
\makeatother %% <- revert @

%% You may want to rename these...
\newcommand*\threedotsord{\mathpalette\superimpose{{\mathop:}{\cdot}}} %% <- normal
\newcommand*\threedotsopen{\mathopen{\threedotsord}}   %% <- spacing like (
\newcommand*\threedotsclose{\mathclose{\threedotsord}} %% <- spacing like )
\newcommand*\threedotsbin{\mathbin{\threedotsord}}     %% <- spacing like +, -, ...
\newcommand*\threedotsrel{\mathrel{\threedotsord}}     %% <- spacing like =, <, ...

\newcommand*\oporder[1]{\threedotsopen#1\threedotsclose} %% <- wraps argument in these

\begin{document}

Using the \verb|\mathopen| and \verb|\mathclose| versions is probably what you want:
\[
    1 + \oporder{ x(t_1) x(t_2) x(t_3) } + \delta
\]

The spacing is nearly always the same as for ordinary atoms though:
\[
    1 + \threedotsord x(t_1) x(t_2) x(t_3) \threedotsord + \delta
\]

Using \verb|\mathbin| or \verb|\mathrel| would be wrong in this context:
\[
    1 + \threedotsbin x(t_1) x(t_2) x(t_3) \threedotsbin + \delta
\]
\[
    1 + \threedotsrel x(t_1) x(t_2) x(t_3) \threedotsrel + \delta
\]

This also works in superscripts and subscripts
\[
    X_{\oporder{xyz}^{\oporder{abc}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that `\mathop` vertically centres its argument with respect to the math axis whenever it is applied to a single character, as remarked e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41266/156366). 
You could also centre the `\cdot` with respect to the `:`, but this is more work (if you want to do it automatically, without guessing the amount to lower it by).

Comment: You can see that the central dot is misaligned in subscripts

Comment: @egreg Oh, I hadn't noticed that. It is aligned correctly when I zoom in on the pdf file. Do you have any idea why it might be off in the screenshot?

Comment: Adjusting to the raster. I had a similar idea, but didn't think to zoom, so when I saw the misalignment I went for a different strategy.

Answer (score 8):

This typesets three dots filling the same height as the colon:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fcolon}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\fcolon@\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\fcolon@}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1:$}%
  \vbox to\ht\z@{%
    \hbox{$\m@th#1.$}%
    \vss
    \hbox{$\m@th#1.$}%
    \vss
    \hbox{$\m@th#1.$}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A:B\fcolon C_{:\fcolon_{:\fcolon}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

If you need subscripts and superscripts to work, needs to be a bit more complicated but...

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


 $ x : x \mathrel{:} x $

 $ x : x \mathrel{\lower.04em\hbox{\rlap{$\cdot$}}{:}} x $

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the tri-colon or vertical ellipsis ⋮ at a font height weight and position to match the colon :
something like the a+⋮xyz⋮+b example (I know its not perfect but given time...)

[image]

but wrapped per another Unicode answer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\UnicodeMathSymbol[4]{%
  \ifnum#1>"FF
    \expandafter\DeclareUnicodeCharacter\expandafter{\@gobble#1}{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\input{unicode-math-table}
\begin{document}
$a+{\lower.2em\hbox{$⋮$}} xyz{\lower.2em\hbox{$⋮$}}+b$
\end{document}
```